# Passing a string value to WSDL API that requires a SHA1 string

Tags: c#, .net, razor

I am new to C# .net but i was using php. i want to achieve the same result as this

```
$var = $username.$jpwMobileNo;
$pass = sha1(utf8_encode($var ));
```

so that i can pass the $pass variable to an API that accepts String for $pass how do i achieve this.
I have tried this

```
var pass = userName + no + time + key;
var p = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pass);
var x = sha.ComputeHash(p);
var str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(x);
var user = new AWsdl.AgencyClient();
var resultAPI = user.GA(userName, no, time, key,str);
```

but the var str returns as a byte .how do i convert it to a string

Comment: I am sure variable `str` is a `string`. How do you mean it is a `byte`?

Comment: Am i doing the right thing to convert back `var x=sha.ComputeHash` to a string yet the API provider require the `var str` to be a string. This is what i did it in php `$str= sha1(utf8_encode($ck ));` `$resultAPI = $client->GA($str);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `Encoding.GetString` to turn the bytes into a string, but that should only be used to turn something back into a string that was encoded into bytes.

Use the `BitConverter.GetString` method to turn the bytes into the same hexadecimal string that the PHP `sha1` function returns:

```
string str = BitConverter.ToString(x).Replace("-", String.Empty);
```

Comment: Thank! that's what i was missing